# Maven build fails with os-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I added the os-maven-plugin to my pom like so:

```
<build>
    <extensions>
        <!-- native platform classifier -->
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

On my dev machine I can compile and run this project just fine, however when I try to run the build via Jenkins it fails immediately and shows this error in the logs:

```
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager getting plugin 
'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin': Plugin 
'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5' has an invalid descriptor:
1) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong group ID: kr.motd.maven
2) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong artifact ID: os-maven-plugin
3) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong version: 1.5.0.Final
```

Clearly, it seems to be using the descriptors from the os-maven-plugin to get the clean-plugin and fails because the descriptors don't match up for that plugin.

Why is this and how should I be incorporating the os-maven-plugin into my project?

Comment: First I would recommend to upgrade the os-maven-plugin furthermore the question is why do you need os-maven-plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise I've upped the version to 1.6.0 and the result is the same. I need to use this plugin because I have a dependency where the version is dependent upon the OS that the project is running on.

Comment: What kind of dependency is this? Furthermore which Maven version do you use? Are you running on plain command line or inside CI solution like Jenkins?